# Select2 dropdown in tags mode auto-scrolls when you click away

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set-up a select2 dropdown in Tags mode.
2. Start typing a tag.
3. With the focus still in the drop down, using the mouse wheel, scroll to a different part of the page.
4. Now click somewhere.

Observed results:
You are scrolled back so the tagging drop down is in the viewport.

You can see this behavior in action on the projects [demo page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags).

Expected results:
Clicking away from the tags dropdown should not affect scroll position.

This is particularly annoying in an app I'm working on because the Save button of a form is off screen. If the user enters a tag, then scrolls with the mouse wheel to the Save button (which IMHO a very intuitive flow when adding a new tag to an otherwise filled out form) and clicks the Save button, the click won't register on the button. Instead the user is auto-scrolled back to the dropdown with focus no longer in the drop down. Now, they could scroll again and click the actual button.

Anybody know how to fix this issue? I have no qualms with updating the source (already had to do so to fix other select2 quirks).

(FWIW, as of now I haven't logged a bug in the Select2 repo, since it seems questionable to me how actively it's being maintained)

Comment: This can be done in HTML much easier with `<a id='whatever'`> and `<a href="#whatever"`.

Comment: @KeeganKuhn But, I don't want to auto-scroll.

Comment: maybe you can override the behavior with jquery [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). Like `$('#tagBoxId').blur(function(){})`

Comment: @lloyd hmmm... sounds hacky as heck because select2 is autoscrolling, so I'd need to keep track of where I was before the autoscroll, let the autoscroll happen, then scroll back to where I was. I 'd really really prefer select2 doesn't do the autoscroll in the first place.